# Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Not Found (on LUKS encrypted partition)

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption

Just got this error message on Dell XPS 17 (dual boot Win10/Ubuntu 20.10):

```
Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

I have LUKS encrypted Ubuntu partition, so boot-repair cannot help. The boot-repair info can be found here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8Cj9Z3r57V/

[GParted output can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sokSH.png)

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Followed [this](https://gist.github.com/samuelcolvin/43c5ed2807e7db004b1058d0c9bfb068) and managed to fix the issue ...

Notes:

- sudo must be used (outside of chroot)
- home_sdb3 is just a tag, can be anything, as long as it matches in cryptsetup luksOpen and cryptsetup luksClose commands
- sdb2 is the boot partition usually less than 1Gb
- grub-install must be used
- the argument to grub-install must be the drive itself (not any partition), which can also be seen in fdisk -l